# не работает jquery.ajax в Apache Cordova приложении

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova

Сделал первое приложение под Андроид, используя Visual Studio и Apache Cordova.
Приложение должно обращаться к стороннему сайту через `$.ajax` с типом `post.
Нормально работает на компьютере в эмуляторе, но после установки в телефон не выполняет запрос`S.ajax`, возвращается`jqXHR.status === 0`, то есть`'Not connect.\n Verify Network.'`;

Проверил, соединение с сетью есть, приложение выводит тип сети соответствующим плагином.

```
var ops = {
    error: function (jqXHR) {
          alert('error: can not load);
     },
     success: function(d1, d2) {
     },
     url: mainUrl,
     async: true,
     cache: false,
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {},
     method: 'post',
     crossDomain:true
};

$.ajax(ops);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам не обходимо посететить сайт: http://cordova.apache.org/
и ознакомиться с документацией.

Возможно вы забили подключить к проекту встроенный плагин

```
$ cordova platform add browser
```

Так же учтите что у вас настроена технология CROS